# How to copy the last 3 columns in a sheet that grows by 1 column each month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to have a sheet2 that always contains only the last 3 columns from sheet1.

Sheet1 starts out with columns having data in columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G, and then grows by one column each month.

So Sheet2 wont grow... Each Month the last three columns will overwrite

The only thing I can find is how to get the Last column

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the last 3 columns from the data range of a sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues().map(r => r.splice(-3));
  console.log(values); // You can confirm the retrieved values in the log.
}
```

- When this script is run, the last 3 columns are retrieved from the data range of "Sheet1".
- If you want to retrieve the last column instead of the last 3 columns, please modify `r.splice(-3)` to `r.splice(-1)`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

### Added:

About your following additional question,

> how do I paste it into "sheet2" columns EFG?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues().map(r => r.splice(-3));
  console.log(values); // You can confirm the retrieved values in the log.

  // Added
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 5, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- By this modification, `values` is put from the column "E".

Comment: Awesome code...  Now that the columns are retrieved... how do I paste it into "sheet2"  columns EFG?

Comment: @Tillthen BigHeart Thank you for replying. From `Now that the columns are retrieved`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `how do I paste it into "sheet2" columns EFG?`, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const lc = sh.getLastColumn();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,lc - 2,sh.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  console.log(vs); 
}
```